# Unable to post a barcode scan into MySQL database from Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to post a barcode scan content into mysql database. I don't understand my error, when I send there is no error displayed but still it does not post. Initially displayed the php script but now shows no action.Here's the code. I'm really stuck here.The activity below is `XyzActivity.java` and the `post1.php` then the `activity_xyz.xml`.

```
 XyzActivity.java

package com.example.boss.classattendance;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;


public class XyzActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{


//private static final String TAG = "AbcActivity";
public static final String KEY_FORMAT = "scanFormat";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "scanContent";
private static final String URL_FOR_REGISTRATION = 
"http://m.y.i.p/test/post1.php";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private TextView greetingTextView;
private Button scanBtn,post,Logout;
private TextView scan_format, scan_content;
String scanContent;
String scanFormat;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xyz);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String user = bundle.getString("username");
    greetingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting_text_view);
    greetingTextView.setText("Hello "+ user);
    scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    scan_format = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
    Logout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
    scan_content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
    post=(Button)findViewById(R.id.post_button);
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


    post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            submitForm();
        }
    });
    Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new 
  Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
  }

  public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
        com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator 
  = new com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }}

   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
   intent) {
    com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult scanningResult = 
   IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
         scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
         scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();

        scan_format.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        scan_content.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
    }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
   }
     private void submitForm(){
    final String scanContent = scan_content.getText().toString().trim();
    final String scanFormat = scan_format.getText().toString().trim();


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
    URL_FOR_REGISTRATION,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

    Toast.makeText(XyzActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {



 Toast.makeText(XyzActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_CONTENT,scanContent);
            params.put(KEY_FORMAT,scanFormat);

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
  }


   }









   post1.php

   <?php

   require_once 'android_login_connect.php';
   $db = new android_login_connect();


    $response = array("error" => FALSE);

    if (isset($_POST['content']) && isset($_POST['format'])) {


     $content = $_POST['content'];
     $format = $_POST['format'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO post (content,format)
     VALUES ('$KEY_CONTENT','$KEY_FORMAT')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
      echo ‘success’;
    } else {

        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
   };
   ?>





  activity_xyz.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/greeting_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Hello, User"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="0.09" />

<Button

    android:id="@+id/scan_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@color/login_button_background"
    android:text="SCAN"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scan_format"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.09"
    android:text="Format"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scan_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button

    android:id="@+id/post_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@color/login_button_background"
    android:text="POST"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logout_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@color/login_button_background"
    android:text="Sign Out!!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />



     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
     $format = $_POST['format'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO post (content,format)
     VALUES ('$KEY_CONTENT','$KEY_FORMAT')";
```

What is `$KEY_CONTENT` and `$KEY_FORMAT`?

Shouldn't it be

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
     $format = $_POST['format'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO post (content,format)
     VALUES ('$content','$format')";
```